# How to copy an array in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, shader

I searched for 'copy' in the SL reference and couldn't find anything related.

If I have:

```
float a[3] = float[3] (1.0,2.0,3.0);
float b[3] = a;
```

Is `b` now pointing to `a`? If I change `b[0]` would that alter `a[0]`?
If the answer is yes, is there a copy function that I could use to a get a clone of `a` and not point to it? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [GLSL - The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6; 5.8. Assignments; page 114](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf)

> Assignments of values to variable names are done with the assignment operator (`=`):
>
> ```
> lvalue-expression = rvalue-expression
> ```
>
> The lvalue-expression evaluates to an *l-value*. **The assignment operator stores the value of *r-value-expression* into the *l-value*** and returns an *r-value* with the type and precision of *lvalue-expression*.

In glsl there is nothing like a pointer or reference or even a "move" assignment. Values are always copied.

Comment: I have same question for hlsl unanswered for quite a long ime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041733. It freaks me out why so few people come up with this question as it is quite unobvious and very simple. This unswer is the closest and only thing I found on the Internet about my question and this post had only one upvote. Strange.