# How to copy an array in HLSL?

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, direct3d11

In *HLSL* I have two arrays:

```
int arr1[2]; 
int arr2[2];
```

I need to copy contents of `arr1` to `arr2`.

Should I iterate through every element?

```
arr2[0] = arr1[0]; 
arr2[1] = arr1[1];
```

Is there any specific *HLSL* tool (like `memcpy()` in *C*/*C++*)?

Or could I just write `arr2 = arr1;` and that will work for me?

Answer (score 0):

`arr2 = arr1` works fine. There is no reason to go through every element and it could add quite a bit of time depending on the number of array elements or their size.